# How to set border-radius just using border property

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set `border-radius` of an element with just using `border` property?

I want the same result as below:

```
#myelement {
  border: 1px solid #535353;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

I want some code like following (but below code does not work):

```
#myelement {
  border: 1px solid #535353 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

And if you know the answer would you mind telling how you find the answer? I just couldn't find it in Google :(

Comment: I don't think you can do this, because `border-radius` is itself a shorthand (for `border-top-radius`, `border-right-radius`, `border-bottom-radius`, and `border-left-radius`.) I imagine it must be separate because you can't put a shorthand property into another shorthand property (`border` is a shorthand property.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, Not possible.

`Formal syntax:  <br-width> || <br-style> || <color>`

you should read [Mozilla's Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) for the `border` property

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for **[border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border#Syntax)** property is:

```
<br-width> || <br-style> || <color>
```

and the meaning of these values:

```
<br-width>
The width of the border of the elements. Default value medium is used if absent
<br-style>
The line style for all four sides of the elements border. Default value none is used if absent
<color>
Denote the color of the border. If not set, its default value is the value of the element's color property (the text color, not the background color)
```

So it's impossible to include `border-radius` inside `border` value